# When to use F-Test versus Chi-Square Test in Analysis of Deviance

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, f-test

I'm choosing a GAM, and when I try to do

```
anova(model.1, model.2, test="F")
```

It gives me a warning message saying that the F test is inappropriate for binary outcomes. Why is this?

I get virtually the same p-value either way.

Comment: The discussion in the help `?anova.glm` looks like it is relevant to your question (though not completely covering the 'why').